# Skipping failed map jobs

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig

Is there a way to skip a single failed map jobs instead on killed the whole job? I have thousands of map jobs all running fine, there is always this annoying last map job that takes forever and eventually kills the big job.

Is there a way to set either a general setting like "ignore on fail" or a percentage of maps that can be ignored?

I am not looking for perfect results with 100% of the data, a good estimation with 95% would totally suffice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use the mapred.max.map.failures.percent(mapreduce.map.failures.maxpercent in new version 2.1.0) and mapred.max.reduce.failures.percent properties to control your job failures

http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/DeprecatedProperties.html